# Is There a Way to Change Government Type in Victoria 2?

Tags: victoria-2

Is There a Way to Change government Type in Victoria 2 because I want to change to a communist to get more mobilization troops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your government type via [reforms](http://www.paradoxian.org/vickywiki/index.php/Governments_and_How_to_Change_Them#Changing_government_by_reforms), [revolutions](http://www.paradoxian.org/vickywiki/index.php/Governments_and_How_to_Change_Them#Revolutions), or [cheating](http://www.paradoxian.org/vickywiki/index.php/Governments_and_How_to_Change_Them#Changing_Government_by_Outright_Cheating). Sounds like you want a quick fix, so here are the quick cheating options:

> If you absolutely, positively need to change government, try the
>   following cheat codes. Like other codes, hit F12 to open up a screen,
>   then type the code (e.g. "event 23111" or "money") followed by
>   [Enter]. When you are finished entering codes, Alt-F12 closes the
>   window.
>
> - event 23111 - Reform to Monarchy, Laws by Decree
> - event 23112 - Reform to Presidential Dictatorship, Laws by Decree
> - event 23113 - Reform to Proletarian Dictatorship, Laws by Decree, One    Party
> - event 23114 - Reform to Constitutional Monarchy, HMS Government
> - event 23115 - Reform to Presidential Dictatorship, HMS Government
> - event 23116 - Reform to Democracy, Parliamentary, Multi-Party System
> - event 23100 - Socialist Revolution (Proletarian Dictatorship)
> - event 23101 - Liberal Revolution (Democracy)
> - event 23102 - Conservative Revolution (Presidential Dictatorship)
> - event 23103 - Reactionary Revolution (Monarchy)